# How do I Select Counts with Spark SQL Without Getting Errors?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, null, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to do a very simple select statement to count the amount of iPod data that is null in my table in spark. My table looks like this

```
-----+------+------+------+----+-----+
| Time|Period|iPhone|  iPad|iPod|  Mac|
+-----+------+------+------+----+-----+
|Q4/98|     1|  null|  null|null|0.944|
...
```

The command:

```
apl_df.select("count(iPod) from apl_tbl where iPod is null")
```

Gives: 
org.`` apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve &#39;`count(iPod) from apl_tbl where iPod is null`&#39; given input columns: [iPhone, iPod, Mac, Period, iPad, Time];; ``

And

```
apl_df.selectExpr("count(iPod) from apl_tbl where iPod is null")
```

Gives:
`org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException:`

Please help me fix this issue and understand the meaning of these errors.

Comment: The where condition must come before select count expr.

Comment: 1.`DataFrame` / `DataSet[Row]` has the method `select` which takes only Columns / Column Names as string. So the first error it cannot find the column in the DF.

2.In the method `SelectExpr` it accepts list of Spark SQL expression. provided expression cannot be parsed and hence exception is thrown

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
apl_df.select("iPod").filter("iPod is null").count()
```

Or, if you want to use more familiar sql syntax, you can try

```
apl_df.createOrReplaceTempView("apl_tbl")
```

`spark.sql("select count(iPod) from apl_tbl where iPod is Null")`

See reference: https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#selectExpr(scala.collection.Seq)